# When C says start up values of global variables are zero, does it mean also struct members? And what is the initial value of a pointer?

Tags: c, variables

When C says start-up values of global[/static] variables are zero, does it mean also struct  members? And what is the initial value of a [global/static] pointer? NULL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is specified by C99 6.7.8p10:

> If an object that has automatic
>   storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has
>   static storage duration is not
>   initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned)
>     zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according
>     to these rules;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively)
>     according to these rules.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all static variables, of whatever type, will be set to zero. That includes pointers - a NULL pointer is a pointer that is set to zero.

Comment: I recall reading multiple times that NULL can theoretically be any number.

Comment: @Lela It can be represented internally as any value, but when you set a pointer to NULL, NULL must be some representation of zero.